# Xdebug doesn't stop on breakpoints using docker on VSCode

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've created an image with this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.3.28-apache-buster
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.8.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
```

then I creted this `docker-compose.yml`

v

```
ersion: '3'

services:
    app:
        container_name: php7.3-xdebug
        image:  'php7.3-server'
        ports: 
            - '9090:80'
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        environment:
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9000 remote_enable=1
```

container runs ok and the xdebug extension sis shown on `phpinfo()`
[image]

and this is the launch.json that I'm using

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}",
             },
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I set a breakpoint the execution doesn't stop

Comment: Xdebug 2 is no longer supported. Please upgrade: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: Enable xdebug log, try to debug and see the log file: it will tell where Xdebug is trying connect to (if at all) and what the response is. If no log is written: 1) check file permissions , 2) Xdebug does not see "debug me" flag anywhere. if #2 then try configuring it to try debug every single request (so no need for looking for "debug me" flags). But overall - upgrade to Xdebug v3, it's a bit easier to troubleshoot there.