# VSCode unable to debug PHP server running in a docker container - erro code#3 missing options

Tags: php, docker, debugging, xdebug

I know there are several questions on StackOverflow regarding this issue.  Trust me I had gone through some of them ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579102/debug-php-with-vscode-and-docker), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734747/vscode-xdebug-php-configuration/52737017#52737017) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662221/xdebug-doesnt-stop-on-breakpoints-using-docker-on-vscode) and a few others).

None of these helped solving the issue.

##### Symptom of the problem

The program won't stop on the breakpoint.

##### My environment

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- IDE:  VS Code 1.85.1
- PHP web app: running in a container having PHP 8.0-apache
- addons: mysqli, xdebug

Test code (has a breakpoint on line#2):

```php
<?php
echo xdebug_info();
#phpinfo()
```

**launch.json**

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "log": true,
    "externalConsole": false,
    "pathMappings": {
      "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "xdebugSettings": {
      "idekey": "VSCODE"
    }
  },
```

**xdebug.ini**

```ini
[xdebug]
#zend-extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.start_with_request=yes 
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

##### Troubleshooting

Inspected the output of `xdebug.log` generated, and this shows a strange problem.

```
[18] Log opened at 2024-01-07 07:43:39.114700
[18] [Config] INFO: Control socket set up succesfully: '@xdebug-ctrl.18'
[18] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[18] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[18] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/chk_mysqli.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.30" protocol_version="1.0" appid="18" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.3.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2023 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[18] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[18] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[18] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[18] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n breakpoint_include_return_value -v 1
[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="breakpoint_include_return_value" success="1"></response>

[18] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n idekey -v VSCODE
[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" status="starting" reason="ok"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>

[18] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n max_children -v 100
[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[18] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[18] Log closed at 2024-01-07 07:43:39.186601
```

The output shows all success but one failure at `feature_set -i 5` above.

> [[invalid or missing options]]>

This is my first time with PHP, so thanks for helping me out on this please.

Comment: **1)** I do not see `idekey` listed in a known features -- https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp#feature-names **2)** It should not cause issues with the actual ability to debug **3)** `idekey` is set in client settings (VSCode in this case) + Xdebug config param (in the actual .ini file or via `-d` param when calling PHP executable) but not during runtime like this AFAIK. **4)** Do not know about VSCode, but PhpStorm does not care about IDEKEY at all (it just ignores it) unless specifically told to use a specific key (e.g. with DBGProxy or in some multi-website scenario perhaps).

Comment: **Side notes:** 1) You are using Xdebug v3.3 but you still have v2 config params (that do nothing in v3) -- you may want to review them and delete old ones if v2 is no longer used. 2) Not a big expert in debugging PHP with VSCode, but `"hostname": "localhost",` may cause issues (VSCode may not listen "properly") -- better delete it and try without it. 3) Most importantly, I do not see any `breakpoint_set` lines -- looks like VSCode have not set any (unless you have removed those lines of the log).

Comment: I think there might be a bug here in Xdebug, where if you try to set a feature that doesn't exist, it also acts as as "run" (you see the status changing to `starting`). The next `feature_set` then also continues (incorrectly), running the script so it ends and VS Code never has the change to set breakpoints.

However, I don't understand why VS Code sends that `idekey` command, as indeed it does not exist. I'll ping the maintainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that there is a `idekey` entry under `xdebugSettings`. These are sent to Xdebug as features, see [docs](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug#supported-launchjson-settings).

If you need to set it, you can do that inside `proxy` in the `launch.json`. VScode debug adapter does not support IDE KEY filtering - without proxy.

However if you do not use dbgpProxy, you don't need the IDE KEY anyway. As LazyOne said, clean up your Xdebug config. `hostname` is probably causing docker connectivity issues.

Here is my suggestion:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "log": true,
    "pathMappings": {
      "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  },
```

```ini
[xdebug]
#zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/xdebug.so
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes 
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't **need** `[xdebug]` in INI files. PHP just ignores these header sections.